# Restoring SQL backup on Amazon RDS database

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-restore

How is it so difficult to find out how to do this? All I need is to run some simple SQL to restore our existing database on a new RDS database.

Tried connecting with SQL Server Management Studio, it won't connect.

Tried using the Database Migration Tool, it doesn't make any sense.

All the documentation for this seems to assume I'm trying to move some monumental database with zero downtime. Literally all I need to do is run an SQL file on a RDS database. Does anybody on earth understand how this works??

Comment: Is this mysql or MS SQL?

Comment: @RodrigoM It's an SQL backup taken straight from phpmyadmin.

Comment: So its Microsoft SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Native backup and Restore. Amazon RDS supports native backup and restore for Microsoft SQL Server databases using full backup files.

Though it wouldn't work on `db.t1.micro` DB instance class.

You can add Native Backup and restore option by doing following according to the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.BackupRestore.html).

> - Create a new option group, or copy or modify an existing option group.
> - Add the option to the option group.
> - Associate the option group with the DB instance.
>
> After you add the Native Backup and Restore option, you don't need to restart your DB instance. As soon as the option group is active, you can begin backing up and restoring immediately.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you cannot connect to the you need to check your RDS security group. Make sure port 3389 is open to your IP,
2. There is good documentation for connecting to RDS from the Management Studio here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html

It states the following:

> After Amazon RDS provisions your DB instance, you can use any standard
>   SQL client application to connect to the DB instance. In this topic
>   you connect to your DB instance by using either Microsoft SQL Server
>   Management Studio (SSMS) or SQL Workbench/J.

Also double check that the RDS instance is on a public subnet *and* that you have allowed public access to it. See those settings in Configure Advanced Settings:

[image: RDS Advanced Settings]

Comment: This is the documentation I tried, and I receive error 258 ("The wait operation timed out")

Comment: I've tried allowing my IP in the security group, and I've also tried allowing all incoming connections. Still can't connect

Comment: Make sure your RDS is on a public subnet, and that you have allowed public access to it.  It may not be.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: I updated the answer with that info. You need to check the VPC subnet design/implementation to make sure the subnet it is on is public.

Comment: I must be really lost because there is no "configure advanced settings" to be found. Am I not able to change these settings after already creating the RDS instance?